# Enumeration problem: Two dice on a $6 \times 6$ board

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Each die represents a player in a board game. The opening for the game involves each player placing their die on a $6 \times 6$ board. Having in mind rotating and reflecting the board and orienting the two dice, how many unique openings are there for this game?

Any hints on how to achieve this result generally will certainly be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: how many ways can you place the 1st player's die on the board. Then, with that die in place, how many ways can you place the 2nd player's die?

Answer (score 0):

If there are $36$ different fields to place the die on, how many possibilities are there for the first and how many for the second die?

Furthermore, you can rotate the board into $4$ different states and reflect into $2$ different states (a total of 8 different states), which all still are distinguishable when the dies are placed.